# Socket Error 110: Connection Timed Out - Android Delphi SMTP Gmail

Tags: android, delphi, smtp, gmail

I am writing a program for Android using Delphi to send an email with data. As is, my app is having connectivity issues.

I have

- set the host to smtp.gmail.com,
- put in my username and password for my gmail account,
- put valid information in for the address and body fields of a TIdMessage,
- made and added an attachment file,
- set the SSL Options for a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL according to the online examples, and
- added all of the SASL Mechanisms Indy offers.

I am using port 587 and have connected to TLS explicitly.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SendBtn: TButton;
    IdSMTP1: TIdSMTP;
    IdMessage1: TIdMessage;
    IdSASLAnonymous1: TIdSASLAnonymous;
    IdSASLCRAMMD51: TIdSASLCRAMMD5;
    IdSASLCRAMSHA11: TIdSASLCRAMSHA1;
    IdSASLDigest1: TIdSASLDigest;
    IdSASLExternal1: TIdSASLExternal;
    IdSASLLogin1: TIdSASLLogin;
    IdSASLOTP1: TIdSASLOTP;
    IdSASLOTP2: TIdSASLOTP;
    IdSASLPlain1: TIdSASLPlain;
    IdSASLSKey1: TIdSASLSKey;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

    procedure SendBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Attachment : TIdAttachmentFile;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdSMTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(idSMTP1);
  IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
  IdSMTP1.AuthType := satSASL;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLCRAMSHA11;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLAnonymous1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLCRAMMD51;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLDigest1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLExternal1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLLogin1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLOTP1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLOTP2;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLPlain1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLSKey1;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.SendBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IdSMTP1.Connected=True then IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
  IdMessage1.From.Address := 'myemail@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'other@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.BccList.Add.Address := '';
  IdMessage1.CCList.Add.Address := '';
  IdMessage1.Priority := mpHigh;
  IdMessage1.Sender.Address := 'myemail@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.Subject := 'Test Data';   //Add Date/time
  IdMessage1.Body.Add('Hello!');
  Attachment := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts, (GethomePath+'/Test.txt'));
  IdSMTP1.Connect;
  IdSMTP1.Authenticate;
  IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
  IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
end;
```

Fails at:

```
IdSMTP1.Connect;
```

Is there a know problem with connecting to Android in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
IdSMTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(idSMTP1);
```

You are creating and assigning a new default-initialized `SSLIOHandler`, instead of using your existing `SSLIOHandler` that is on the Form.

The line should be this instead:

```
IdSMTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
```

In fact, *everything* you are doing in `FormCreate()` can (and should) be done in the Form Designer at design-time instead. You don't need to do it in code.

Also, I do not see a `TIdUserPassProvider` on your Form.  Most of the SASL components you are using require one for their username/password.  The `TIdSMTP.UserName` and `TIdSMTP.Password` properties are only used when `AuthType` is `satDefault`, not `satSASL`.

Other than that, I would suggest some additional changes in `SendBtnClick()`:

1. You should call `IdMessage1.Clear()` so you don't carry over existing data from previous sends.  You are appending new values to `IdMessage1.BccList`, `IdMessage1.CCList`, `IdMessage1.Body`, and `IdMessage1.MessageParts` without clearing out the old values first.
2. You do not need to call `Authenticate()`, `Send()` does that internally for you.
3. `Send()` should be in a `try/finally` or `try/except` block so you can call `Disconnect()` even if `Send()` fails.
4. you are not configuring `TIdMessage` correctly for mixing text and attachments together.  You *should* add a `TIdText` to the `MessageParts` instead of using `TIdMessage.Body` (however, if `TIdMessage.ConvertPreamble` is true, it will convert `TIdMessage.Body` into a `TIdText` for you if there are any attachments present). But either way, you need to set the `TIdMessage.ContentType` property to `'multipart/mixed'` so the receiver knows there are multiple pieces.

Try this instead:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    SendBtn: TButton;
    IdSMTP1: TIdSMTP;
    IdMessage1: TIdMessage;
    IdSASLAnonymous1: TIdSASLAnonymous;
    IdSASLCRAMMD51: TIdSASLCRAMMD5;
    IdSASLCRAMSHA11: TIdSASLCRAMSHA1;
    IdSASLDigest1: TIdSASLDigest;
    IdSASLExternal1: TIdSASLExternal;
    IdSASLLogin1: TIdSASLLogin;
    IdSASLOTP1: TIdSASLOTP;
    IdSASLOTP2: TIdSASLOTP;
    IdSASLPlain1: TIdSASLPlain;
    IdSASLSKey1: TIdSASLSKey;
    IdUserPassProvider1: TIdUserPassProvider;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;

    procedure SendBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // all of this code can be handled at design-time instead!

  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;

  IdSMTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
  IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
  IdSMTP1.AuthType := satSASL;

  IdSASLCRAMSHA11.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProvider1;
  IdSASLCRAMMD51.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProvider1;
  IdSASLDigest1.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProvider1;
  IdSASLLogin1.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProvider1;
  IdSASLOTP1.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProvider1;
  IdSASLOTP2.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProvider1;
  IdSASLPlain1.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProvider1;
  IdSASLSKey1.UserPassProvider := IdUserPassProvider1;

  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLCRAMSHA11;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLAnonymous1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLCRAMMD51;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLDigest1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLExternal1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLLogin1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLOTP1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLOTP2;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLPlain1;
  IdSMTP1.SASLMechanisms.Add.SASL := IdSASLSKey1;

  // end design-time capable hookups

  IdSMTP1.Host := ...;
  IdSMTP1.Port := ...;
  IdUserPassProvider1.UserName := ...;
  IdUserPassProvider1.Password := ...;
end;

procedure TForm1.SendBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Text: TIdText;
  Attachment : TIdAttachmentFile;
begin
  if IdSMTP1.Connected then IdSMTP1.Disconnect;

  IdMessage1.Clear;
  IdMessage1.From.Address := 'myemail@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'other@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.Priority := mpHigh;
  IdMessage1.Sender.Address := 'myemail@gmail.com';
  IdMessage1.Subject := 'Test Data';   //Add Date/time
  //IdMessage1.Body.Add('Hello!');
  Text := TIdText.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts);
  Text.ContentType := 'text/plain';
  Text.Body.Add('Hello!');
  Attachment := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage1.MessageParts, (GethomePath+'/Test.txt'));
  IdMessage1.ContextType := 'multipart/mixed';             

  IdSMTP1.Connect;
  try
    IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
  finally
    IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That was a very thorough answer! Thank you very much for your help. This doesn't, however, allow my app to actually send the email. I got an error that said to log in via my web browser and an email from google that said an app without enough security tried to access my account. Any thoughts on how to get around that? I thought we were conforming to the standards for security by using TLS. Again, thanks!

Comment: You are not getting a TLS error, you are getting an Authentication error. Encryption (security for socket transmissions) and Authentication (your Google identity) are two different things. You need to go into your Google account and either 1) enable ["Less secure apps"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255), then Indy can login using your normal Google password; 2) turn on 2-step verification and then generate an ["App-specific password"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) for Indy to use instead of your normal password.

Comment: At this time, Indy does not implement OAuth, especially over SASL (though I think there may be some 3rd party implementations floating around), which is why `TIdSMTP` cannot login using your normal Google password unless you lower your Google security settings, or generate a separate password just for Indy.

Comment: Wow! This is awesome! That's interesting and good to know. The attachment doesn't work this way though. The program just hangs when the send button is clicked, but works when the two lines about the attachment are commented out.

Comment: @DelphiAndroid12: I can't answer that. you will have to debug it yourself and find out what is actually freezing. Does the file exist? Are you sure you are using the current path to it? Do you have permissions to access the file? In any case, you shouldn't be performing blocking operations in your main UI thread to begin with, especially on Android (it is likely to kill your app!). Your button start a worker thread to handle the email sending outside of the UI thread.

Comment: You are right--I must not be using the correct path to the file. GetHomePath+'/Test.txt'    does not work in this case. It does work to read back the contents of my file into a memo. Any thoughts on what to do about this?

Comment: @DelphiAndroid12: If the path works when loading the same file into a Memo then it should also work for `TIdAttachmentFile` as well. A path is a path regardless of how it is used.  Make sure the file is not already open for writing access when you send the email, as `TIdAttachmentFile` opens the file with `fmShareDenyWrite` access.

Comment: How exactly do I check that and what do I do about it?

Comment: @DelphiAndroid12: This discussion is moving way beyond the scope of the original question. Please post a new question about the `TIdAttachmentFile` issue, the original question about the socket timeout issue has been addressed. And please debug your code to figure out what is really happening. You should not be getting a freeze. If there is a problem accessing the file, you should be getting an exception raised.

Comment: OK. Thank you for all of your help!